# How to compare the sign of two columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns. I want to compare the signs of each element in the column and see when it differs. It is easier to see with an example.

This is the dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(COL1 = rnorm(15, 0, 1), COL2 = rnorm(15, 0, 1))

 COL1        COL2
1   0.01274137 -0.97966119
2  -0.48455106  1.19248167
3  -0.79149435 -1.45365392
4  -0.18961660  0.02216361
5  -0.34771000  1.39026672
6   0.28199427  0.49143945
7  -0.28650800 -0.71676355
8  -0.29677529  1.13092654
9  -0.24240084  0.99432286
10  2.13540200  0.66348347
11  1.94442199  0.53371032
12 -1.63108069 -0.21556863
13  0.38334186 -0.91472900
14  1.15981803 -0.54540520
15  1.04363634 -1.68835445
```

I would like to have a code that compares the signs of COL1 and COL2 and tells me when it differs. The outcome should be:

```
# rows where the sign differs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about multiplying the columns together and getting the sign with `sign`?

```
which(sign(data[,1] * data[,2]) == -1)
[1]  1  2  4  5  8  9 13 14 15
```

Comment: thanks a lot! All the answers work very well, I just marked as the correct one the code I am more familiar with, but all work perfectly fine, thanks!

Comment: Be careful if you have NA values, I edited my answer below to work with NA cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve sign of each element with `sign`, and `which` retrieves the index of the inequalities

```
which(sign(df$COL1) != sign(df$COL2))
```

Edit: Warning, all three current answers above fail when there are `NA` values.

```
set.seed(4)
df2 = data.frame(COL1 = rnorm(15, 0, 1), COL2 = rnorm(15, 0, 1))
df2[1, 1] <- NA

          COL1       COL2
1           NA  0.1690268
2  -0.54249257  1.1650268
3   0.89114465 -0.0442040
4   0.59598058 -0.1003684
5   1.63561800 -0.2834446
6   0.68927544  1.5408150
7  -1.28124663  0.1651690
8  -0.21314452  1.3076224
9   1.89653987  1.2882569
10  1.77686321  0.5928969
11  0.56660450 -0.2829437
12  0.01571945  1.2558840
13  0.38305734  0.9098392
14 -0.04513712 -0.9280281
15  0.03435191  1.2401808

which(sign(df2$COL1) != sign(df2$COL2))
[1]  2  3  4  5  7  8 11

which(sign(df2[,1] * df2[,2]) == -1)
[1]  2  3  4  5  7  8 11

which(df2$COL1 < 0 & df2$COL2 > 0 | df2$COL1 > 0 & df2$COL2 < 0)
[1]  2  3  4  5  7  8 11
```

Here is a solution that works if you have `NA` values, which tests equality and retrieves index when equality values are not in `! ... %in% TRUE`, as opposed to `!= TRUE`

```
which(!(sign(df2$COL1) == sign(df2$COL2)) %in% TRUE)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8 11
```

Compare output of

```
! NA %in% TRUE
[1] TRUE
NA != TRUE
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply logic comparing the columns if they're are `<` or `>` zero.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(COL1 < 0 & COL2 > 0 | COL1 > 0 & COL2 < 0)
```

The index of rows can be obtained using `which`

```
which(df$COL1 < 0 & df$COL2 > 0 | df$COL1 > 0 & df$COL2 < 0)
```